# How to hide the nav and nav-pills class for Bootstrap with LESS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I have been having problems trying to hide certain classes in Bootstrap - this one has given me some of the most trouble.  Here I would like to hide the use of the nav & nav-pills classes, but if I remove them & embed them in .pills > ul using LESS and adjust all of my code accordingly, the pills themselves will not render, which puzzles me.  After spending hours trying to fight it, I grudgingly embedded the classes into the document, but I still hope to remove them.

Here is the HTML/PHP:

```
        <section class="pills" id="mus-art">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Artist1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist4</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist5</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist6</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist7</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist8</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist9</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist10</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist11</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist12</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist13</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Artist14</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section id="contributor-info1">
                <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/locationoffile"; ?>
        </section>
```

I do not have anything in my LESS file that interferes with any rendering of pills.  I also use some jQuery, but only for changing what pill gets the active class when it gets clicked.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? use the `class="nav nav-pills"` by default with all `ul` without mentioning it in the html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not list all the rules that you adjusted, but the pills are not just set by the `ul.nav.nav-pills` selector. The actual pills are the `<a>` elements, and their style is set by their `.nav-pills` ancestry. For example :

```css
.nav-pills > li > a
/* OR */
.nav-pills > .active > a:hover
```

If you want not to use the `.nav-pills` class, you have to redefine all those rules, implying directly the elements on which this class is set or any rule that is using this class in its selector.

---

But IMHO, hiding those classes presents no interest for the end-user, the only interest is to hide the use of the framework from fellow developers, or bots - unless you encountered a conflict with those classes, in which case you should present this problem directly.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying here - I kinda wished that wasn't the case, but as far as I can tell from digging into the less files, you're correct.